# How can I close the Dialog and then also return a message once it was succesfully updated on the database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, supabase

I'm using Next.js with Shadcn and Supabase. In my datatable, each row has a dropdown with actions, and clicking on an action opens a dialog to cancel an order.

What is expected to happen: Once I clicked `confirm` it should close the dialog and return a message that says `Successfully updated it on the database`.

What currently happens:

- Clicking `confirm` does not close the dialog.
- No return message as I am unsure of how I can implement this with the Shadcn DataTable
- The function `updateOrder` does function correctly and data is reflected in the database.

**Colums**

```
export const columns: ColumnDef<Order>[] = [
  {
    id: "actions",
    enableHiding: false,
    cell: ({ row }) => {
      const order = row.original

     return (
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="ghost" className="h-8 w-8 p-0">
              <span className="sr-only">Open menu</span>
              <MoreHorizontal className="h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
          </DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
            <DropdownMenuLabel>Actions</DropdownMenuLabel>
          <DropdownMenuSeparator />
            <DropdownMenuItem 
              onClick={() => updateOrderStatus(row.original.order_id)}>
              Deliver Order
            </DropdownMenuItem>
            <Dialog>
              <DialogTrigger>
                <DropdownMenuItem onSelect={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                  Cancel Order
                </DropdownMenuItem>
              </DialogTrigger>
              <DialogContent>
                <DialogHeader>
                  <DialogTitle>Are you sure absolutely sure?</DialogTitle>
                  <DialogDescription>
                    This action cannot be undone. Do not forget to call the customers
                    as why you have cancelled their order.
                  </DialogDescription>
                </DialogHeader>
                <DialogFooter>
                  <Button type="submit" variant="destructive" onClick={() => updateOrder(row.original.order_id)}>Confirm</Button>
                </DialogFooter>
              </DialogContent>
            </Dialog>
            <DropdownMenuSeparator />
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
      )
    },
  },
]
```

**UpdateOrder**

```
export const updateToCancelledOrder = async (order_id: string) => {
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const supabase = createServerActionClient({ cookies: () => cookieStore })

    try{

        const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('orders')
        .update({ order_status : 'Cancelled' })
        .eq('order_id', order_id)  

        return { message: 'Successfully updated it on the database' }
        revalidatePath('/')

    }catch(error){
       return { message: 'There was an error.' }
    }
}
```

**DataTable** This is just the same as the example from here: https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/data-table

```
export function DataTableDemo() {
  const [sorting, setSorting] = React.useState<SortingState>([])
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = React.useState<ColumnFiltersState>(
    []
  )
  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] =
    React.useState<VisibilityState>({})
  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = React.useState({})
 
  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    state: {
      sorting,
      columnFilters,
      columnVisibility,
      rowSelection,
    },
  })
 
  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <div className="flex items-center py-4">
        <Input
          placeholder="Filter emails..."
          value={(table.getColumn("email")?.getFilterValue() as string) ?? ""}
          onChange={(event) =>
            table.getColumn("email")?.setFilterValue(event.target.value)
          }
          className="max-w-sm"
        />
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="outline" className="ml-auto">
              Columns <ChevronDown className="ml-2 h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
          </DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
            {table
              .getAllColumns()
              .filter((column) => column.getCanHide())
              .map((column) => {
                return (
                  <DropdownMenuCheckboxItem
                    key={column.id}
                    className="capitalize"
                    checked={column.getIsVisible()}
                    onCheckedChange={(value) =>
                      column.toggleVisibility(!!value)
                    }
                  >
                    {column.id}
                  </DropdownMenuCheckboxItem>
                )
              })}
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </div>
      <div className="rounded-md border">
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                  return (
                    <TableHead key={header.id}>
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                    </TableHead>
                  )
                })}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
              table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={row.id}
                  data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                >
                  {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                    <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                      {flexRender(
                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cell.getContext()
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              ))
            ) : (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell
                  colSpan={columns.length}
                  className="h-24 text-center"
                >
                  No results.
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-end space-x-2 py-4">
        <div className="flex-1 text-sm text-muted-foreground">
          {table.getFilteredSelectedRowModel().rows.length} of{" "}
          {table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length} row(s) selected.
        </div>
        <div className="space-x-2">
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            size="sm"
            onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
          >
            Previous
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            size="sm"
            onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
          >
            Next
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```